# How to implement an asynchorous callback on REST requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest

I have a C# REST Service application, that handles a bunch of incoming HTTP requests, some of them are POST, some of them are GET. They are generally standard. I implement a bunch of Web API controllers that contains Routes to handle those HTTP request.

```
public class MatchController : ApiController
{
    [Route("FindMatchAsIndividual")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FindMatchAsIndividual(string playername)
    {
         //Add player name to matchmaking list
         //if there is a match, return json string representation of a match
    }
```

}

But my use case is to implement a 1v1 matchmaking service. For a matchmaking service, imagine that many players can make a POST request using the "**FindMatchAsIndividual**" method.

For each call, I add the player name to a list. When there are 2 player names in the list, create a callback to "**FindMatchAsIndividual**", at which point a json representation of the match can be sent back to whoever made the REST API call.

To implement something like this, obviously it has to be asynchronous. Each call to "**FindMatchAsIndividual**" only adds 1 player name to the list, and we can't create a match with only 1 player. We need to wait for another player to make a call to "**FindMatchAsIndividual**" before we can create a 1v1 match and return a result.

What is the best way to do something like this? One way is to start a background thread/task, use EventHandlers to make callbacks to the **FindMatchAsIndividual** method. I am not sure where to create the thread though. I thought I might put it  **WebAPIConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        Thread thread = new Thread(RunMatchMakingService);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Search terms: "SignalR", "long poll" should get you started on understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at SignalR. My worry with client side polling is the amount of extra requests generated though and it probably won't scale. On client side, I would have to poll very consistently as on the server I can't predict how long it will take before a match is made to reduce the polling rate

Comment: You need a persistent connection between client and server. That usually means websocket connection, but libraries like SignalR mentioned above can abstract details away for you.

Answer (score 0):

when a player call the api,add the player to the list,when the number of players over 1(there may be many players),mark first 2 players in cache list,then return the result to the player by name,and remove these two players from cache list.

Comment: My question is more about how to do that asynchronously, as I don't know whether I should create a thread or not, or use polling or something else and what is the best choice.

Comment: [Route("FindMatchAsIndividual")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FindMatchAsIndividual(string playername)
    {
         //Add player name to matchmaking list
         //if there is a match, return json string representation of a match
        await Task.Run(()=>{
// wait player to join
     })

    }